# Is there a way to limit the memory buffer pool for a database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have several databases on an instance of MS SQL Server 2012. Using Glenn Berry's DMV queries, I see the memory buffer pool used by each database.

Is there a way I can limit AltDB to only use a maximum of 10GB. My goal is that more memory is used by MainDB.

```
DB     | Memory Buffer Pool in GB
MainDB | 34.00
AltDB  | 24.00
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can limit AltDB to only use a maximum of 10GB.

No, [not even with Resource Governor](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2011/04/19/restricting-memory-using-resource-governor.aspx).

From [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191475.aspx)

> The Database Engine supports a performance optimization mechanism called read-ahead. Read-ahead anticipates the data and index pages needed to fulfill a query execution plan and brings the pages into the buffer cache before they are actually used by the query.

A good article to read : [The clock hands of the buffer cache](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/the-clock-hands-of-the-buffer-cache/)

> My goal is that more memory is used by MainDB.

Another alternative is to have `MainDB` on a different instance capped by Max Memory. This way you can reduce the max memory for `AltDB`.

Comment: Putting it on a separate instance - this is a great suggestion and really your only option. Unless you want to create a job that monitors buffer pool usage by database, and sets that database offline/online when it finds it has gone over 10GB. But that is like using a tank to get rid of a squirrel.